# E0289 отсутствуют экземпляры конструктура

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++17, c++14

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string_view>
#include <string>
std::string_view LoL()
{
    std::string str{};
    std::getline(std::cin >> std::ws, str);
    return str;
}
int main()
{
    std::string_view x{LoL};
    std::cout << x;
    return 0;
}
```

не компилируется пишет

Ошибка (активно)    E0289   отсутствуют экземпляры конструктора "std::basic_string_view<_Elem, _Traits>::basic_string_view [с _Elem=char, _Traits=std::char_traits]", соответствующие списку аргументов   getline E:\c++\getline\Source.cpp   12

что делать

Comment: Вы кардинально изменили вопрос!!! Это неприемлемо! Вам отвечали на вопрос **E0289 отсутствуют экземпляры конструктура**, вы же его изменили полностью, тем самым ставя ответивших в положение идиотов, отвечающих совершенно не на то!

Comment: прошу простить меня ведь я совсем не разбираюсь в понятиях stackoverflow и подумал что лучше не создавать по миллиону запросов чтобы люди отвечали на мелкие и бесмысленные вопросы а просто поменять исходный запрос:(

Answer (score 2):

В строке

```
std::string_view x{LoL};
```

вы передаете в качестве аргумента адрес функции `LoL`, а не результат ее вызова.

```
std::string_view x{LoL()};
```

Просто интересно, сколько секунд вы пытались решить этот вопрос самостоятельно?

И еще —

```
std::string_view LoL()
{
    static std::string str{};
```

или

```
std::string LoL()
{
    std::string str{};
    std::getline(std::cin >> std::ws, str);
    return str;
}

int main()
{
    std::string lol = LoL();
    std::string_view x{lol};
    std::cout << x;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `std::string_view` привязывается к локальной переменной, уничтожаемой при выходе из функции `LoL`.

Comment: @wololo А там копирование не происходит? я со `string_view` плотно не работал... Кстати, я не отвечал на вопрос о выводе, а только об ошибке E0289 — отсутствуют экземпляры конструктора...

Comment: Не происходит. В том и задумка, что `std::string_view` не должен делать лишних копирований. На cppreference [есть похожий пример](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_basic_string_view). Да я видел первую версию вопроса, но мне почему-то подумалось, что ТС сперва пытался вызвать функцию. Увидел билеберду в консоли. Потом попытался это исправить устранив вызов функции. Оно вообще перестало компилироваться. И на этом идеи решения проблемы исчерпались :)

Comment: @wololo OK, спасибо, в любом случае я ответ подправил.

Answer (score 1):

Вы не вызываете функцию `LoL`

```
std::string_view x{LoL()};
```